# Pivot a Large Table in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have Large Data Set which have 72000*3 (rows* columns). This is non-pivoted
data. When I convert these data into pivot table the ValueError occurred.

Here is a my dataset example

```
UserID   MovieID   Ratings  
    35     16107         3  
  4498     16107         4  
  1915     16108         3  
 17615     16108         5  
  1075     16108         3  
  2067     16108         4  
  4808     16109         5  
  4391     16109         3  
  4160     16110         3  
  7543     16110         4  
   119     16111         1  
   119     16112         3
```

---

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity 
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/AA/Desktop/movierating.csv")
print(df1) 
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index='UserID',columns='MovieID',values='Ratings').fillna(0)
print(df1)
```

raises

```
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine? Seems like you don't have enough memory available for this operation.

Comment: How many unique MovieIDs and UserIDs are there?  You are looking at a data frame that has `MovieID.unique().size` x UserID.unique().size` elements as floats.  At 20000 x 10000 unique values, with a float64 dtype, you are looking at ~1.6 GB of memory, just for the floating points in C.

Comment: i have 20000 unique MovieIDs and 16000 UserIds    #James